# Vuetify - overlay text closing transition with carousel

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

What's up everyone! My name is Jay, I am new to web design and been using Vuetify for my first web project.

Right now, I have a carousel setup and some overlay text placed at the center of each carousel item. Every time you click the arrow button (next image/previous image), the text in the next slide will show up with a fade-in transition.

I got the fade-in part done already (not sure if I am doing this the right way though). I have the fade-in transition css and simply assign the css to my text:

**Code**:

```
<v-carousel
dark
hide-delimiter-background
height = "600"
>
    <v-carousel-item
    v-for="(item,i) in items"
    :key="i"
    :src="item.src"
    eager
    reverse-transition="slide-fade"
    transition="slide-fade"
    >
        <v-container fill-height>
            <v-row
            class="white--text mx-auto"
            >
                <v-col
                class="white--text text-center"
                >
                    <span
                    :class="[$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown ? 'display-2' : 'display-3']"
                    >

                    <p class = "animated fadeInUp">Animation line 1</p> // The fade-in transition
                    <p class = "animated fadeInUp">Animation line 2</p> // The fade-in transition

                    </span>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

**CSS**:

```
.animated {
-webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
animation-duration: 1s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@keyframes fadeInUp {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
    }
}

.fadeInUp {
    -webkit-animation-name: fadeInUp;
    animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

**My goals here is**:

**Creat fade-out transition for the overlay text as well**. When a user click the arrow button to go to next/previous image, all the text at the center will fade-out in a sec.

There are **two challenges I see here so far**.

**First**, how to trigger the fade-out transition or is that even possible?

**Second**, how to stop the carousel from switching to next/previous image before the text fade-out transition is completed (I am guessing some sort of delay)?

Here is a live demo of the design I want to re-create, you can see the carousel right under the navigation bar: https://baker.qodeinteractive.com/

I don't know where I can start to tackle this, it is driving me crazy! I also ran into the transition classes in Vue yesterday, but I am not sure if that is the right way to go. If you have experience with similar designs like this in the past or if you know how to re-create this design, I would appreciate if you could teach me or drop me some hints!

Thank you so much for your time reading my post, stay safe!

Comment: Heya and welcome to SO. Can you create a reproducible example of your scenario, a codesandbox for example? It's a lot easier for us to tweak and test your code that way

Comment: Hello Rie! Thanks for following up!

I have put together a simplified example of what I have right now: https://codepen.io/JNDesignco/pen/WNrpKjN

My goal is to implement something like this: https://baker.qodeinteractive.com/

You can see the carousel right under the navigation bar in the demo website above

Please let me know if that is sufficient, would be happy to provide additional information if needed. Thanks!

Comment: The info definitely is sufficient but I personally have no idea on how to add a fade-out animation before the page transitions, sorry! Tried a few things but couldn't get it to work at all.

Comment: Hey Rie, no worries! Appreciate you for helping out man!